# SDK says: an old certificate or corrupted sdk x zip file

Tags: curl, certificate, installation, sdkman

After you have given a command: sdk install  at beginning downloading is starting, but stopped with curl certificate error or corrupted .zip archive file problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps reason was, that I gave command 'apt-get dist-upgrade', but)
here is a shortcut to this problem:

- edit .skdman/etc/config file and add this line:

sdkman_insecure_ssl=true

and save

- sdk install  again. And it should work!